# How to store additional code sections in FLASH memory (AVR, GCC)

Tags: linker, avr-gcc, atmega

I am working with AVR ATmega328p MCU and I would like to add constant string at address 0x7000 into flash memory. How can I do this with AVR-GCC?

My code contains this declaration:

```
// Firmware version
static volatile char version[16] __attribute__ ((section (".fwversion"))) = "0.01 DEV";
```

Now, when I run gcc with this flags:

```
avr-gcc -Wl,--section-start=.fwversion=0x7000 -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=8000000UL -Os -Wall -o main.elf main.c
```

The ELF file contains section `.fwversion` and after `avr-objcopy`, there are data at address 0x7000 in iHEX file.

But when I run gcc with `-Wl,--gc-sections` flag:

```
avr-g++ -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--section-start=.fwversion=0x7000 -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=8000000UL -Os -Wall -o main.elf main.c
```

the `.fwversion` section is removed.

I need to use `-Wl,--gc-sections` flag but I also need constant string stored in flash memory. What flags should I use to achieve this?

---

Is it possible to use something like this in GCC?

```
static volatile char version[16] __attribute__ ((section (0x7000))) = "0.01 DEV";
```

Comment: Are you saying that `avr-objdump` doesn't show the `.fwversion` section in `main.elf`?

Comment: Yes, `.fwversion` is removed in ELF, thus the code is not in HEX file.

Comment: There are reasons why it would not be in the HEX, separate of whether or not it's in the ELF.

Answer (score 0):

I think static volatile char is just not the thing you mean. Maybe const char, like this:

```
const char version[16] __attribute__ ((section(".fwversion"))) = "0.01 DEV";
```

Also notice memcpy_PF function.

Answer (score -1):

I am unsure why it needs to be at that certain address unless you want it available for the bootloader.

[This Program Memory link](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html) discusses the functions that are available for storing and accessing flash memory from locations.
Typically you store and access strings in flash memory by using the `PSTR` command.
E.g.

```
char str[16] = PSTR("I am a string\n");
```